# How can I build in release in Visual Studio 2010 (C# Express)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, release

I'm used to VS2008, in which a release build would be built upon pressing F6, or in the menu Build > Build Solution.

The build menu is gone, and although I can build the solution (through F6), it only builds the debug.

I assume there is some kind of configuration manager now, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right-click solution > Configuration manager.
Sorry for not looking more before asking.

Comment: +1 AND Thanks for not looking and asking - that's how I found how to do it :)

Answer (score 35):

If you have no Build Menu in Visual Studio 2010 Express, go to the menu Tools -> Settings -> select 'Expert Settings'

Answer (score 4):

Also see this thread:
[How to switch between debug/release in Visual c# 2010 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812423/how-to-switch-between-debug-release-in-visual-c-2010-express/2938880)

Answer (score 4):

### Microsoft Visual C# 2010 express:

I hope you are facing a problem to get the build for release(.exe).

I hope the following steps will help you.Anyway i faced such a problem and solved by this.good luck.

Build > configuration manager > set active solution configuration to Release

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the same question that has not been propagated here yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127008/78162
Namely, you also need to go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions and turn on "Show advanced build configurations."