# Visual Basic Deployment

Tags: setup-deployment

I am using Visual Basic 2010 express to create some simple forms that play short videos.  I had read on a previous stackoverflow response (which I can't find now!) that you just need to go to the project>bin>release folder and copy the application exe file as well as the dll files to the device you want to deploy the form to.

This worked great at first, but as I make improvements to the form in 2010 express, the improvements don't seem to show up in the deployment.  It's as if the new device is seeing old versions of the application.

Are there other files I should be moving over to the device in addition to the exe and dll files?

Thanks in advance.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not do a release build. Try doing a release build.

Refer thread: [How to switch between debug/release in Visual c# 2010 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812423/how-to-switch-between-debug-release-in-visual-c-2010-express/2938880)
Or right-click Solutions -> Configuration manager